# Comment Self-Removal Time-Limit

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

A comment self-removal time-limit either doesn't exist, or is too long.

Why are users allowed to delete comments days after they posted them?

I think users shouldn't be allowed to delete their own comments after a certain amount of time has passed, like 3 days or so, as an example.

I think that gives incentive for dishonest people to remove comments they are unhappy with several days after they post them.

Comment: Moderators can still see comments; if you have a serious complaint about a comment, flag for moderator attention and they will look into it. The ability to remove comments at any time is important - many people use it to "clean up" when an issue has been resolved. Also, I don't see how removing comments you made in the heat of an argument (maybe after a good night's sleep) is "dishonest"

Comment: I've experienced, several times, where a user and I had a couple exchanges, and he ends up deleting his comment some 20 days in the future, which makes it look like I'm talking to myself. Also, why all the downvotes? Did I post incorrectly?

Comment: downvotes on Meta are used to express disagreement with a feature request

Comment: In that case, why not erase your own comments, if they don't add anything new to the table. Comments weren't made for discussion rather for adding detail or asking for more information.

Comment: @JoeSimmons Comments are not permanent: they're transient and second-class citizens. On _some_ Stack Exchange sites, like Stack Overflow, they are left around, but on others, like RPG.SE, they're actively purged and have very limited lifespans. I will also often delete my own comments if they don't need to stay around, or once a discussion is resolved (which should not even really happen in comments), and when I do so I will flag the other side's comments as obsolete. If the other side's deleted their comments, and yours don't need to stay around, you can just delete them.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: But what if they do add detail? The only thing is, I look somewhat like a loon since it looks like I'm talking to myself.

Comment: @Joe Add all detail in the comments to your post by **editing**. Possible side effects: bumping the post, so that more people might help you.

Comment: People know that comments can be deleted for various reasons. They won't think you are a loon. They'll assume you are wearing a Bluetooth headset somewhere :)

Comment: Additional side effect: important information about your question is found _right there inside it_, not buried in amongst a dozen comments which might get deleted. Useful information brought up in comments on your own question should _almost always_ be edited into the question itself if it's worth keeping around. Or to put it differently: if something would be _lost_ by nuking all the comments, make sure it won't be lost when they are. (The same applies to comments on your own answers)

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: I'm unable to edit my comments that were made on Oct 3rd, 2013. I could delete all the comments and make a new one, but I don't want to notify the asker *(and/or the answerer)* because I couldn't edit. What is the ideal solution to that problem?

Comment: @JoeSimmons He means edit them **into your question or answer** so that they can be safely deleted without losing anything. Vital information should *not* be hidden away in comments.

Comment: ps: I'll remind myself not to post in meta again. My rep will probably get to zero in a couple more questions... simple discussion questions, and I lose all my rep.

Comment: @JoeSimmons You have lost 12 imaginary unicorn points on a website on the internet. (And I just gave you 10.) That is being a bit dramatic. If you're on Meta.SO (or SO), you need to not care very much about downvotes, since they're going to happen - but upvotes can happen too, and it takes five downvotes to cancel out a single upvote.

Comment: @JoeSimmons reputation on Meta is a funny beast, since votes are generally used to express (dis)agreement. While it's easy to lose, it's also a lot easier to gain than [SO].

Comment: @Joe rep is really, really meaningless on Meta (even more so than on Stack Overflow), and *one* upvote on an answer will even it all out. It's almost impossible to not make that small loss up if you stick around

Comment: I don't care about the rep. I care that 9 people *(and growing)* down-voted someone trying to spark a discussion. **this is not a feature request, why would people down-vote?**

Comment: @JoeSimmons I went through the same when I first started participating on meta a few weeks ago. I proposed an unpopular feature request, getting 22 downvotes and 1 upvote. I therefore lost 39 points in reputation. Answer this question alone (+6 so far) just got me 60. Seriously, you really should care about reputation loss on meta, since is extremely volatile due to the nature of this specific site.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: I don't care about the rep. Read my above comment.

Comment: @JoeSimmons 9 people disagree with you, me included, and disagreeing is part of the discussion. There's no offense to be taken here.

Comment: Not agreed **at all**.

Comment: @JoeSimmons I side with you on voting being weird and unreasonable here: people might say "voting = (dis)agreement" thing, but sometimes it also means a low quality question or weird stuff. Reputation shouldn't really _exist_ on a meta site; this one's an odd one out for historical reasons. Also, this _is_ a feature request, really: you're saying you think people shouldn't be able to delete their comments, and there is not actually much invitation or opportunity to discuss anything here. There is just a demand for something comment-related and a need to explain how comments work here.

Comment: `this is not a feature request, why would people down-vote?` Well, you said "I think users shouldn't be allowed to delete their own comments after a certain amount of time has passed, like 3 days or so, as an example." That counts as a feature request on Meta, and I assume the downvotes are disagreement with that (The question itself is perfectly fine)

Comment: That *IS* what **I** think. I wanted to see what others think. I actually thought the feature already existed. I was, in no way, requesting that feature. I now know how comments work, and I still hold the belief expressed in my original "question".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ability to remove your own comments at any time is an important feature, and shouldn't be taken away.

Many people use it to remove obsolete discussions without involving a moderator to do the cleanup.

Also, hiding bad content is an explicit part of Stack Exchange's community philosophy anyway. We don't let it rot on the street to show everybody what a jerk the author is. Users can flag offensive comments; if enough of them do that, the comment goes away *even without moderator attention*. Moderators will delete offensive comments on sight anyway. You'll agree that in light of all this, preventing the author of the badness from removing it - while the rest of the community can! - doesn't make sense.

Don't worry: deleting your own comments doesn't get you off the hook if you wrote something really, really bad.  Moderators can still see deleted comments. If you have a serious complaint about a comment that was deleted, flag for moderator attention and they will look into it.

Also, I wouldn't say that removing comments you made in the heat of an argument  is "dishonest" in the first place. It's happened to me a couple of times that I removed things I said after a good night's sleep. When that happens, it's arguably a *good* thing.

Answer (score 10):

In an ideal Q&A site comments shouldn't exist at all. From the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about):

> Ask questions, get answers, no distractions

Comments exist with the only purpose of refining the content of a post and **not** for extended discussions.

It's consider **good** practice to remove comments whenever appropriate, for instance when the OP clarifies their question and the comment is now useless. You said (in the comments, consider moving this to the question):

> I've experienced, several times, where a user and I had a couple exchanges, and he ends up deleting his comment some 20 days in the future, which makes it look like I'm talking to myself.

People are aware that comments can be easily deleted: nobody will think you are crazy, just that there's some missing comment you are replying to.

The other person decided to remove his comments since he though they weren't worth to stay there. If you notice something like this, it's a wonderful occasion for deleting your comments as well and keeping the post as clean as possible.

Bottom line, the focus should be on the **content** of a post, not on the comments. Locking the comments after X days, as you suggest, would directly go against the fundamental principles of StackOverflow.

Comment: Joking comments are also good targets for self-cleanup; generally fine and enjoyable in the moment, less and less important (and maybe blocking other comments from view) as time goes on.

Comment: *[making a joking comment to clean up later]*

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no such thing, and for good reasons.

Answers are sometimes given in *comment form*. Although not the best practice, it exists on several try-and-solve kinds of questions, that aren't later converted into answers.

Besides, there is nothing wrong for someone to delete *their own* comment - it's theirs anyway. If they are unhappy with their own comments, they can delete them.